# Decode Yahoo search results URL's

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium, web-scraping

I'm working on an application that's written in Ruby and uses selenium to scrap through Yahoo search results and pull the title description and URL from each link on each result page.

My problem is the URL's I'm getting look like this:

> http://r.search.yahoo.com/_ylt=AwrBTzoAL7RVc9sAXT9XNyoA;_ylu=X3oDMTByOHZyb21tBGNvbG8DYmYxBHBvcwMxBHZ0aWQDBHNlYwNzcg--/RV=2/RE=1437900673/RO=10/RU=http%3a%2f%2fen.wikipedia.org%2fwiki%2fSomething/RK=0/RS=wtfzdVploHxkh.UDtV9YvqVD56w-

What I need, is just the URL for the site and not the Yahoo search side of it. I've been told this is possible through PHP uses a function like this:

```
function translateurl($line) { 
$c="0123456789abcdef" ;
for ($a=0;$a<16;++$a) { for ($b=0;$b<16;++$b)
$tr["%".$c[$a].$c[$b]]=chr(($a*16)+$b) ; }
$a=explode("http",$line) ; $b=explode("/",$a[2]) ; $u="http".$b[0]; 
$url=strtr($u,$tr) ; return $url ; 
}
```

I've been able to convert all of it to Ruby except for the section that's:

```
$tr["%".$c[$a].$c[$b]]=chr(($a*16)+$b)
```

I kind of understand how this is working, but I feel like this should be easier in Ruby with Selenium. At the moment, my only work around for this is to just open the link in a new tab and take the URL from there. But it takes a lot of time to do so and would just be easier to convert the URL without opening the link.

My current Ruby code:

```
def translate_url(url)
       c='0123456789abcdef'
       for a in 0..16
         for b in 0..16
           tr = ['%' + c[a] + c[b]]
           tr((a*16)+b).ord
         end
       end

       a = ('http' + url).split(', ')

       b = ('/' + a[2]).split(', ')

       u = ('http' + b[0])

       return_url = strtr(u,tr)
       return_url
end
```

Any ideas?

Comment: scrape yahoo search? sure that's not against their terms ;)

Comment: I haven't seen anything about it being against their terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decoding the url itself can be done via ruby [URI](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html) module. The bigger challenge is to get only the right part out of the path. You could do something like this:

```
URI.decode(yahoo_url).match(%r{RU=(.*)/RK}).captures
```

This gives you a list of matched content, so in your example `["http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Something"]`

But beware this regex only works if the url you want always comes after RU= and is followed by /RK.

Comment: just what I needed! Thanks!